# Magento 2 - What is base dir for file?

Tags: magento2, error

I use following code,

```
public function execute()
{
    //do your custom stuff here
    $fileName = 'file name for download here';
    $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        null, //content here. it can be null and set later 
        base dir of the file to download here
        'application/octet-stream', //content type here
        content lenght here...can be null
    );
 }
```

What would be the base dir for this file?

> /magento/pub/media/downloadable/files/links/l/e/learn-magento.jpg

Comment: r u using linux or windows.. ?

Comment: Server is unix!

Comment: and you are using apache2? means your /var/www/html folder

Comment: Yes I am using apache2

Comment: Magento throws error: "unknown Directory Type"

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221238/magento-2-download-wrong-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Getting Base url For Directory you can follow this.

```
    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Action\Context $context
    ){
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getBaseDir() {
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('your_path');
        return $path;
    }
```

Pass Your Directory in `getAbsolutePath('Here')`

Answer (score 2):

**By ObjectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

echo $rootPath  =  $directory->getRoot();
```

**By Factory Method**

```
protected $_dir;
...

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    ...        
) {
    ...
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to call that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. you look over there.

Comment: @L.Klmn It's working for you.?

Comment: I think yes, the file is located here: /var/www/medienshop-dev/magento/pub/media/downloadable/files/links/l/e/learn-magento.jpg and the value of baseDir is the same. However it still says "Unknown Directory Type".